# Securing a PHP data request for code injection

Tags: php, sql, security, code-injection

The small website I am managing for my club is currently seeing an increased amount of attack attempts. Until now those attacks have not been very sophisticated and therefore nothing happened (yet). Now  I just want to make sure that the way we request content is as protected as possible and not a huge hole in our defence. For that I think I need additional changes to the code, but don't really know where to start.

The setup:
We load our content pages by using $_GET arguments to tell which site to get and then get parsed to a database to get more data for the specific site. This is all done using a rewrite rule so we don't have to use `index.php?arg1=this&arg2=that` as our URL but can use `/pages/arg1/1rg2`

The code:

The rewrite rule looks as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?arg1=$1&arg2=$2 [B,NE,L]
```

The code to then request the data from the database:

```
$statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM `navigation` WHERE `Name` = :arg2");
$statement->bindParam(":name", $name);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetch();
```

Now what I think i need to do is make additional checks for the arg2 string before I hand it to the database request, since I'm not sure if the binding actually prevents injections, but I am not sure what to check for as the string itself could contain special characters like

> à l' ù

and likewise symbols like

> ; . _ ( ) -

so I can't just check if it is letters. I though about using regex to check if that string matches anying, like so:

```
if (!preg_match("/^([0-9a-z_\s; ._à'ù()-])+$/i",$arg2)) {
        echo "Non valid string";
        exit;
  }
```

But I am not sure if this is enough to prevent code injection to either the php request or the database or at wore even both?
Do you guys have any tips or idea on how to close it down even more, so that only valid entries (i.e. non code text) will actually result in a query to the system? Or did I already do that and there is - for now - nothing more I can do?

Comment: _"since I'm not sure if the binding actually prevents injections"_ - of course it does; that is _the point_ of prepared statements after all, that the query syntax and the data do _not_ get mixed together into one string value.

Comment: The parameter binding prevents SQL injection yes. What other types of code injection are you worried about? Obviously any vulnerability depends entirely on the context in which you then use the inserted data.

Comment: `the string itself could contain special characters like

à l' ù` ...not sure how you imagine these sorts of characters have anything to do with any kind of code injection. and `; . _ ( ) -` are all pretty arbitrary, and are also competely valid, normal parts of regular prose text too, so completely chopping them out is likely to simply vandalise regular data.

Comment: If you're echoing any of this data into a web page at any point, you can prevent XSS scripting attacks by HTML-encoding the data. But you would do that at _output_ time, not at input, since the vulnerability is only an issue in that specific context at that specific moment - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php